# WiFiManager - Combine NonBlocking portal AND addParameter

Tags: wifi

I wish to config `WiFiManager` and `addParameter` of MQTT topic and local server on its ConfigPortal.

Additionally in a case of a power outage or any, in case of losing WiFi, to continue in a `NonBlocking` way.

The problem is when combining both features in one sketch, I get some errors.

Entire code is ( please notice comments marked `Marker[i]` ):

```
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#define MQTT_SERVER "192.168.3.200"
WiFiManager wm;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_server("mqtt_server", "mqtt server", MQTT_SERVER, 40);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_user("mqtt_user", "mqtt user", "", 10);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_pwd("mqtt_pwd", "mqtt password", "", 10);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_topic("mqtt_topic", "mqtt topic", "", 10);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_group("mqtt_group", "mqtt group", "", 10);
  WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_root("mqtt_root", "mqtt rootTopic", "", 10);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_server);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_user);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_pwd);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_topic);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_group);
  wm.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_root);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); // explicitly set mode, esp defaults to STA+AP
  //  wm.resetSettings();

  //  wm.setConfigPortalTimeout(180);
  // wm.setConfigPortalBlocking(false);  // <--- Marker [#1]

  //  if (!wm.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP")) {
  //    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
  //    delay(3000);
  //    //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
  //    ESP.restart();
  //    delay(5000);
  //  }

  bool res;
  res = wm.autoConnect("test123", "password"); // password protected ap
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //  wm.process(); //<--- Marker [2]
  Serial.println("hi");
  delay(100);

}
```

1. When `Marker[1]` & `Marker[2]` are commented out ConfigPortal works as expected, and in `Blocked` state - meaning there is no `hi`'s on Serial monitor.
2. When only `Marker[2]` is commented out, ConfigPortal is reached, lacking all `addParameter` fields.
3. When `Marker[1]` & `Marker[2]` are not commented out, ConfigPortal is now reachable, but not having Non-Blocking feature...
4. What is the purpose of `wm.process()` ?

Guy

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: @jsotola see at the bottom of code. It is noted already

Comment: autoConnect will end the portal if WiFi can connect. use `startConfigPortal` to let the portal run. wm.process handles client of a started wm web server. see the OnDemandNonBlocking example's doWiFiManager function

Comment: @Juraj - thanks for clarifying. I saw the usage of `wm.process()` only in NonBlocking example, and as far as understood in use only when Portal in hosted while not connected to WiFi ( what is traditionally - Blocking mode ). Is it correct ?

Comment: @Juraj Can you explain about `startConfigPortal` and why it is not used in relevant built in example ?

Answer (score 2):

The WiFiManger's `autoConnect` function starts the configuration web server (and AP) only if connection to configured WiFi network is not established.

If you want to run the WiFiManger's web server to reconfigure WiFi or to set other parameters, you can start the WM web server with the `startConfigPortal` function.

`autoConnect` and `startConfigPortal` are blocking by default. The library has a loop inside this functions which runs until the web server is stopped calling [Exit] action on the configuration web page or the timeout set with `setConfigPortalTimeout` is reached after last contact from browser.

To run the WM web server 'parallel' to your sketch you can configure it as not blocking with `setConfigPortalBlocking(false)`. Then to allow WM handling of the web server the sketch must periodically call `wm.process()`.

In not blocking mode the [Exit] action on the configuration wen page doesn't stop the web server. The server must be stopped in code.

The parameter definitions must by global in sketch, if you want to run WiFiManager with parameters outside of setup(). Parameters local in setup() don't exist after setup() finishes. WiFiManager detects this and doesn't use the parameters.

The `OnDemandWebPortal` example and `OnDemandNonBlocking` example demonstrate `startConfigPortal` in blocking and not blocking use.

Comment: If I didn't explain myself right - I'm looking on 2 scenarios: 1) first time boot, creditials have to be set ( including `addParameter`'s ) 2) After some failure which WiFi is not found for some reason, I need my system continue running ( minus All WiFi + MQTT functionality ), during THIS time I rather have `ConfigPortal` accessible for some time ( 180 sec ).

Comment: @Guy.D, now you have the insight to do that

Comment: please review my answer below